# Pointer Arithmetic and Bubble Sort (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, math

I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I had taken notes today in class, but unfortunately my OneNote crashed and deleted all of my notes from today. I know there is something I am missing, but I cannot figure it out. I have been searching all over my textbook, and even looked online for over an hour. I can't seem to find anything that works.

I know my mistake is probably the fact I am using charPtr++ in an if or a set variable statement, but I do not remember how to do this. How do I check if one element is less than the other?

**We are supposed to use Pointer Arithmetic to write a descending bubble sort of 10 elements. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and why my program is not outputting anything but the original array? Thanks!**

**We also cannot use bracket or offset notation.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // DRIVER PROGRAM

    char *characters, *charPtr = nullptr; // Array or undefined size.
    fstream fs; // file stream for file arithmetic


    fs.open("array.txt", ios::in); // Open the file
    char currentChar; // Used to check if the file can still be read.
    int counter = 0; // Counter to check how many elements are in the array.
    while (fs >> currentChar) { // While data can be put into counter, continue...

            counter++; // Add one to counter

    }

    characters = new char[counter]; // Sets size of array.
    charPtr = characters;

    fs.clear(); // Clears eof flag.
    fs.seekg(0, ios::beg); // Sets pointer back to the beginning. CHECK IF YOU CAN REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE ONE ABOVE.

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) { // While less than the size of array.

        fs >> charPtr; // Write to charPtr
        cout << *charPtr << " "; // Output array.
        charPtr++; // Move to next element

    }

    fs.close(); // Close file
    putchar('\n'); // Output newline efficiently.
    charPtr = characters;

    // BUBBLE SORT

    bool swapChar;
    char temp;

    do {

        swapChar = false;


        for(int count = 0; count < (counter - 1); count++) {

            if (*(charPtr) < *(charPtr++)) { // If character at 0 is less than the character at 1

                temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
                *(charPtr) = *(charPtr++); // set character at 0 to character at 1
                *(charPtr++) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp
                swapChar = true; // set swap to true 
                cout << *charPtr << " "; // output current swap
                charPtr++; // add 1 to charPtr
            }

        }
    } while (swapChar == true);

}
```

Comment: There's a lot of `charPtr++` that you probably should not have. Try stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger to make sure it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately I am using CodeBlocks and it will not allow me to debug a single file. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Step one in learning C++ is to learn about the Standard Library, and in particular, `std::string`. Don't treat it as fancy C. If you do need the raw characters for sorting purposes, you can dump them out with `c_str()`.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `charPtr++` increments itself. In the below block of code you did 4 increments and you would have expected only one. You should replace it with `*(charPtr+1)` instead.

```
if (*(charPtr) < *(charPtr++)) { // If character at 0 is less than the character at 1 
    temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
    *(charPtr) = *(charPtr++); // set character at 0 to character at 1 
    *(charPtr++) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp 
    swapChar = true; // set swap to true 
    cout << *charPtr << " "; // output current swap
    charPtr++; // add 1 to charPtr 
}
```

Comment: Would this not be considered offset notation?

Comment: Also `charPtr[1]` which is less ugly in terms of notation.

Comment: Everytime you did `*(charPtr++)` you actually read  `*(charPtr)` and executed `charPtr = charPtr + 1`

Comment: I changed all *(charPtr++) to *(charPtr+1) and it still does not work.

Comment: I suggest putting in a debugger or printing debug logs to find the cause. But, i have two questions, why are you not breaking out of loop when `*(charPtr+1)` is null. And should the if check be reverse? `if (*(charPtr) > *(charPtr+1)) ` for ascending order?

Answer (score 1):

First there are far too many `++`, second you should outfactor some essential functionality like the swap (so that you can test it independently), thirdly you don't set the charPtr correctly after each run.

```
if (*(charPtr) < *(charPtr++)) { // If character at 0 is less than the character at 1
            // swap
            temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
            *(charPtr) = *(charPtr++); // set character at 0 to character at 1
            *(charPtr++) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp
            swapChar = true; // set swap to true 

            cout << *charPtr << " "; // output current swap


            charPtr++; // add 1 to charPtr
        }
}
```

Lets rewrite the code a bit

```
            // swap
            temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
            *(charPtr) = *(charPtr++); // set character at 0 to character at 1
            *(charPtr++) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp
```

and the swap function

```
void swap(char *firstPtr, char *secondPtr) {
    char temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
    *(firstPtr) = *(secondPtr++); // set character at 0 to character at 1
    *(secondPtr++) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp
}
```

This makes it a bit better, but the `++` is still wrong, they should not be there in the swap as we just want to swap first and second.

```
void swap(char *firstPtr, char *secondPtr) {
    char temp = *(charPtr); // Set temp to character at 0
    *(firstPtr) = *(secondPtr); // set character at 0 to character at 1
    *(secondPtr) = temp; // set character at 1 to temp
}
```

The program is still wrong

```
char *nextPtr = charPtr; // moved this out of the condition as we need it later.
        if (*(charPtr) < *(++nextPtr)) { // If character at 0 is less than the character at 1
            // swap
            swap(charPtr, nextPtr);
            swapChar = true; // set swap to true 

            cout << *charPtr << " "; // output current swap

            charPtr++; // add 1 to charPtr
        }
```

Is the condition right? it seems like your sorting reversed, change `<` to `>` if its wrong.

The last

```
            charPtr++; // add 1 to charPtr
```

You do only if you swap ... else you check exactly the same again.

```
    char *nextPtr = charPtr;

    if (*(charPtr) > *(++nextPtr)) { // If character at 0 is greater than the character at 1
            // swap
            swap(charPtr, nextPtr);
            swapChar = true; // set swap to true 
    }
    cout << *charPtr << " "; // output current position

    charPtr = nextPtr; // check the next char
}
cout << endl; // change line after each pass through
```

So more errors than lines of code ... try to run it through the debugger to find if there are more.